# moment-duration-format.d.ts Definition Not Extending Moment Module

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

Any idea why this doesn’t work or how I can extend the duration interface to support the format function?

```
declare module 'moment' {
     interface Duration {
       format(template: string, precision?: string, settings?: any): string;
     }

}
```

when used as:

```
moment.duration(minutes, 'minutes').format('mm');
```

I’m getting the error that ‘format' does not exist on type ‘Duration'

Answer (score 12):

First, install types:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/moment-duration-format
```

Second, import them in your file:

```
/// <reference path='../..your-path.../node_modules/@types/moment-duration-format/index.d.ts' />
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-duration-format';
```

Then you can use

```
moment.duration(minutes, 'minutes').format('mm');
```

Comment: `npm install --save-dev @types/moment-duration-format` solved my problem, while `npm install moment-duration-format` didn't.

Answer (score 11):

Imports:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-duration-format';
```

Outside of your class, define the interfaces:

```
interface Duration extends moment.Duration {
  format: (template?: string, precision?: number, settings?: DurationSettings) => string;
}

interface DurationSettings {
  forceLength: boolean;
  precision: number;
  template: string;
  trim: boolean | 'left' | 'right';
}
```

Then in your code:

```
const duration = moment.duration(minutes, 'minutes') as Duration;
return duration.format('mm');
```

If you defined your `Duration` interface in another file, you will need to export and import it as well.

Comment: I'm still getting errors in my code.   Property 'duration' does not exist on type 'typeof 'moment''.

Comment: I'd need to have a look at your code to better understand where your error comes from. But do have a look at my answer, I updated the interface definitions. I don't think it will solve your problem, but once fixed, it will provide better autocomplete.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the following dependencies installed:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/moment-duration-format": "2.2.2",
  "moment": "2.24.0",
  "moment-duration-format": "2.3.2"
}
```

If that's the case then you need these imports in the exact same order:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-duration-format';
```

Afterwards you should be able to do this:

```
const seconds: number = Math.floor(process.uptime());
const formatted: string = moment.duration(seconds, 'seconds').format({
  precision: 0,
  template: 'y [years], w [weeks], d [days], h [hours], m [minutes], s [seconds]',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `namespace` instead of `module`

```
declare namespace moment {
     interface Duration {
       format(template: string, precision?: string, settings?: DurationSettings): string;
     }

}
```

and settings for  "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2"

```
        interface DurationSettings {
                trim: boolean | 'left' | 'right';
                useGrouping: boolean;
                usePlural: boolean;
                useLeftUnits: boolean;
                precision: number;
                useSignificantDigits: boolean;
                trunc: boolean;
                forceLength: boolean;
                minValue: number;
                maxValue: number;
                largest: number;
        }
```