# How to use moment-duration-format in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I am using moment.js in my TypeScript (Ionic2/Angular2) project. Following on from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042337/how-to-format-decimal-hours-greater-than-24-hours-into-hours-minutes-in-javascri), I now want to try out a plugin [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format)

I have the npm package and the type definition and am able to use by import as..

```
import moment from 'moment';
...
let duration = moment.duration(decimalHours, 'hours');
```

I now want to use [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format)

I have installed via `npm install moment-duration-format --save` and then the type definition via `npm i @types/moment-duration-format --save`.

I can see both npm modules.

As always, there is always some mystery on how to use such type definitions (the useage including import never seems to be in any doco).

I have tried adding `import 'moment-duration-format';`, `import duration from 'moment-duration-format';` (moment-duration-format/index.d.ts' is not a module.)

I get an error when trying to use as follows..

```
let dd = moment.duration.format(400.99, 'hours').format('D:HH:mm');

// (TS error [ts] Property 'format' does not exist on type '(inp?: DurationInputArg1, unit?: DurationConstructor) => Duration'.
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to use this in *TypeScript*.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was using the workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383393/moment-duration-format-d-ts-definition-not-extending-moment-module/41412055#41412055), but it now looks like the ype def has been fixed. Getting an update of the type def So I can do the following...

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-duration-format';

let duration = moment.duration(decimalHours, 'hours') ;   
let options : moment.DurationFormatSettings   = {
  forceLength : false,
  precision : 0,
  template : formatString,
  trim : false
};
let result  = duration.format(formatString, 0, options);
```

Comment: how did you update the type definition? which version? I am using the latest (moment 2.29.1 and moment-duration-format 2.3.2) and I'm still getting type issues.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `duration` as a property instead of invoking it. Try:

```
let dd = moment.duration(400.99, 'hours').format('D:HH:mm');
```

This is actually not a TypeScript problem. It wouldn't work with JavaScript either. In JavaSctript you would get a runtime error while TypeScript doesn't let you do it at compile time (proving its worth).

Comment: Thanks for that, but still can't get it to work, as do not know how to import. I have `import moment from 'moment';
import  'moment-duration-format';` and then try the above but I get the TS error `[ts] Property 'format' does not exist on type 'Duration'`. I just cannot get it to "see" the `moment-duration-format` plugin. Also tried `import duration from 'moment-duration-format';` but that does not work either.

Comment: you need install the typing definition "@types/moment-duration-format"

Comment: and --save-dev ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem...

It seems as if there is an error in the type definition. Others have same issue as you can see here: https://github.com/souldreamer/noti-cli/blob/ef104c22792e0dfeb67d3372b04e231d45ffaa55/src/shared/pipes.ts#L38

There was a fix for the problem as part of a pull request on github, that unfortunately has been closed without merging:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/14327

As a temporary workaround, you could use the line of code of the first link. As second step we should try to create a new pull request on github, to get the problem fixed in future releases.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as R_B_ correctly worked out a wrong type definition in the typings module for moment-duration-format.

I'll create a new pull request for this, as my last was closed because of lint errors.

So long you can use a custom type definition in your project as done here
https://github.com/TwoStone/leaderboard/blob/develop/subprojects/webapp/src/custom-typings.d.ts
Just create the file in your project and it should work for the moment.